# Back4App support for user data segregation

Tags: database-design, back4app

im in the process of choosing a backend technology for a new app, and i have a few questions for those how are using back4app. I cant share publicly all details, but what it does is basically a POS.

When i saw back4app for the first time i was pretty excited by how much it does, and how it can accelerate my development.

First let me share some of core requirements of my app. Its an app that will be mobile first and after we will develop an web app for it.

In this app, we will host several companies (company account) , where each company can have up to 3 users, who will share view of the company data, but their data will not be shared among the full userbase. Some users will have access to some elevated functions while other wont.

The data structure is the same for every company, so my main requirement is to have a database system that provides (and having a backend like back4app is a plus, but a welcome plus), that allows:

- Data segregation per company account
- ACL per user account into the company
- Integral data structure

Summing up, what i need is an scalable backend that allows me to have multiple companies running into the same database. Does back4app provides this level of data isolation? If so its a core element of the system?

Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 0):

There are many applications built on Back4App by other developers with architecture similar to what you need (some of them are also POS systems). There are two approaches you can choose from:

- Create an "app" for each company. You even can automate the app creation via API. The advantage here is more isolation and flexibility among different companies. The main disadvantage is additional complexity to maintain the application on the long run.
- Create a single "app" for all the companies. In this case, I'd create a Role (or set of roles) for each of the companies, add a company's users to its role and make sure all company's objects are restricted to the role.